# Green's function for the screened Poisson equation in an n-dimensional ball

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, poissons-equation

Consider the screened Poisson equation $\Delta u(r) - cu(r) = -g(r)$, in a ball (centered at the origin) of radius $R$, with boundary condition $u(R)=0$.

In 3-dimensional space, the Green's function for the above equation is given by

$G(r, R) = \frac{1}{4 \pi r}\frac{\mathrm{sinh}(R-r)\sqrt{c}}{\mathrm{sinh}(R\sqrt{c})}$,

as mentioned in this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0041555369900706).

I am interested in finding a similar expression for this Green's function that generalizes to higher dimensions ($n>3$). So far I have looked into the article's cited [source](https://archive.org/details/koshlyakov-smirnov-gliner-differential-equations-of-mathematical-physics-1964) and Duffy's [Green's Functions with Applications](http://nguyen.hong.hai.free.fr/EBOOKS/SCIENCE%20AND%20ENGINEERING/MATHEMATIQUE/ANALYSE/Green%27s%20Function%20with%20Applications.pdf), but have not been able to locate or derive the general expression for higher dimensions.

I would appreciate any guidance on where and how to find such an expression.